# Detect SIM change OR find IMSI of the SIM using official iOS SDK?

Tags: iphone, ios, imei, msisdn

I am developing an app for a mobile carrier. First I wanted to find any of the things (IMSI, ICCID, IMEI, MSISDN) so that I can detect if the SIM is related to my mobile carrier. But I guess Apple doesn't allow that.

Now as a workaround I will ask the user to register his phone number with my app. But then again bad things will happen if user changes the SIM.

Is there any way for me to detect SIM change using the official iOS SDK?

Comment: If no SIM is inserted, `CTCarrier.isoCountryCode` returns `nil`. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#DOCUMENTATION/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CTCarrier/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009596-CH1-SW1

Comment: but i want to detect a SIM change...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to determine if the SIM/Phone number has changed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10872117/is-it-possible-to-determine-if-the-sim-phone-number-has-changed)

Comment: Take into account that it is possible to change the phone number without changing SIM card.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

should sign up for a notification using **`subscriberCellularProviderDidUpdateNotifier`** in http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CTTelephonyNetworkInfo/Reference/Reference.html

but, you're only be notified if the swap occurs while your app is running. 
you're still be unable to detect if the user changes the SIM to another SIM from the same operator when your app is not running.

Comment: is this worked at your end? how you did it can you help me i tried below code but not working 

  info.subscriberCellularProviderDidUpdateNotifier = { inCTCarrier in
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
 print("sim changed")
            })
        }

Answer (score 6):

You can get access only on jailbroken device.

Find file on path `/private/var/root/Library/Lockdown/data_ark.plist`

the key is `InternationalMobileSubscriberIdenti`