# Detect SIM card replacement

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

Is there any way to know if the user has changed his SIM card with a different SIM card?

really what I want to do is to know from which number he is using right now, I mean if so far he used some phone number and now he changed his phone number to a different number, can I detect it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detect SIM change OR find IMSI of the SIM using official iOS SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11789357/detect-sim-change-or-find-imsi-of-the-sim-using-official-ios-sdk)

Answer (score 0):

You can not read sim number with public api. You can only detect if the sim card is changed, take a look to [Core Telephony Framework Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CoreTelephonyFrameworkReference/_index.html).

When you detect a sim card change you can ask nicely the user to enter his phone number and validate it via an sms system.