# How to detect sim change in iOS

Tags: ios, sim-card

I'm implementing the currency transfer  mobile app and i have to fetch the information about something that is unique on particular iOS device. I HAVE TO DETECT sim change.

I went through many links[how to identify ios device uniquely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19179799/how-to-identify-ios-device-uniquely#comment34664042_19179896)

and

[Is it possible to determine if the SIM/Phone number has changed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10872117/is-it-possible-to-determine-if-the-sim-phone-number-has-changed)

but they are of no use, plus it cant be detected if user removes sim when app is not running.

Comment: Have you taken a look at Core Telephony? Something like "carrierToken" might be what you need.

Comment: @Ravi_Parmar Did you found solution for your problem? I have the same problem how to detect SIM swap when an app is not running.

Answer (score 0):

You should sign up for a notification using subscriberCellularProviderDidUpdateNotifier in

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CTTelephonyNetworkInfo/Reference/Reference.html

you can detect sim changing only while app is running.

For sim change detection while app is not running refer the below link

[Detect SIM change OR find IMSI of the SIM using official iOS SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11789357/detect-sim-change-or-find-imsi-of-the-sim-using-official-ios-sdk)

Hope it helps!!

Comment: If he also wants to detect the change **between** launches of his app (not while it's running), perhaps he can read `CTTelephonyNetworkInfo`'s property `subscriberCellularProvider`, serialize it (save to disk) some how and compare the values between launches of the app.

Comment: but the thing is what if user changes the sim while app is not running?