# Detect changes to phone carrier

Tags: ios, sim-card, carrier

I want to detect changes to phone carrier (i.e.. Maxis, DiGi, Celcom). How can I do this? I found this link:

[Is it possible to determine if the SIM/Phone number has changed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10872117/is-it-possible-to-determine-if-the-sim-phone-number-has-changed)

But is it usable for iOS 7 and later & also safe to use? (meaning Apple won't reject the app as this app will be released into App Store).

Answer (score 0):

[`CTCarrier`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CTCarrier/) and [`CTTelephonyNetworkInfo`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CTTelephonyNetworkInfo/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CTTelephonyNetworkInfo/subscriberCellularProviderDidUpdateNotifier) are public classes available in the SDK, so yes, Apple will accept apps that incorporate these into the app store.

I was very intrigued by the [`subscriberCellularProviderDidUpdateNotifier`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CTTelephonyNetworkInfo/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CTTelephonyNetworkInfo/subscriberCellularProviderDidUpdateNotifier) dispatch block, but more than likely what you'll want to do is simply check to see if the carrier name has changed each time your app is launched or brought back to the foreground.